# jQuery + Django: transfer 350KB of textual data from server to client?

Tags: jquery, django, transfer

I'm building a Django-based website with jQuery used at the front-end. One aspect of it is that the server sends 200 records of the following format to the front-end:

```
field_1: up to 1000 character text
field_2: up to 200 character text
field_3: up to 200 character text
field_4: up to 200 character text
field_5: up to 200 character text
field_6: a boolean value
```

What the front-end will do is basically display those records one by one without page reloads, i.e. using JavaScript/jQuery.

So my question is - what would be the most convenient way to transfer those ~350KB of mostly textual data from Django to jQuery, so that those records could be stored conveniently at the client side (only for the length of the session, of course) for the purpose outlined above? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on what you are going to do with the data on the client. Just display it as text in something like 200 <div> tags? Or is the client going to have to work with this data? In which case you might want to send it as JSON data. Then it can be read by Javascript straight into a data structure.

Comment: It will only be displayed, only one record (of 5 text fields) at a time. So on the client side there will only be like 5 DIVs, displaying one record, and, to put it simply, a "Next" button, so when the user presses it - the next record is put in those 5 DIVs and shown.

Comment: I'd get each one as needed using the jQuery .load() method which can load content straight into an element, without page reload, and wrapping all the Ajax complexities. So your 'next' button would just be five .load() calls, and your Django server has a URL pattern and a view which just sends one of your chunks.

Answer (score 1):

From the extra information you've provided, I'd say just serve the data as a regular Django template, which you call as needed one at a time. You should only need to ping the server once per `next`, not 5 times per next. Serve it up as regular HTML, and use jQuery to load that fragment directly where it needs to go. Don't bother with JSON for this, it's more work for very little (if any) gain.

Example:

```
#urls
url(r'^record/(?P<record_id>\d+)/$', 'site.views.record', name='record')

#views site/views.py
def record(request, record_id):
    obj = Record.objects.get(id=record_id)
    return render_to_response('site/record_partial.html', {
       'obj': obj
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#templates site/record_partial.html
    <div> {{ obj.field1 }} </div>
    <div> {{ obj.field2 }} </div>
    <div> {{ obj.field3 }} </div>
    <div> {{ obj.field4 }} </div>
    <div> {{ obj.field5 }} </div>

# Page
<div id='fields'>
</div>
<div id='next' data-page='3'> next >> </div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var next = $('#next').click(function() { 
        var page = $(next).data('page');
        $('#fields').load('/site/record/' + page + '/', function() {
            $(next).data('page', page+1); // incr page number
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: And if I'd had the time to type that all in I would have :) +1

Comment: @Spacedman I +1'd you too - to be fair, your comments answered this, I figured I could get some cheap rep on the back of your answer =)